# SQL Find following session - different logic than cross join

Tags: sql, hive, gaps-and-islands

I have a set of data that stores two types of sessions.  It is mobile data usage versus wifi data usage.

```
ID  Session_Type
1  Cell
2  WiFi
3  Cell
4  Cell
5  WiFi

.
.
.
.
1000 Cell
1001 WiFi
```

Desired Results

```
Cell_ID. Next_WiFi_sess_id
1        2
3        5
4        5 
.
.
1000    1001
```

I have gotten to the extent of joining the table by itself and done such that an id is > than the wifi id, but I am sure if this is perfect solution.  Can you do this in a Lag for better performance?

```
select a.id, b.id
from 
table a
join table b
where a.id > min(b.id)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window functions -- specifically, a cumulative minimum:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             min(case when session_type = 'WiFi' then id end) over (order by id rows between current row and unbounded following) as next_wifi_id
      from t
     ) t
where session_type = 'Cell';
```

Comment: Thank you Gordan for always helping, this was helpful just a few mins shy :(

Comment: @epv . . . Actually, you can check the times.  This was over 2 minutes *before* the other answer.  I wouldn't normally consider a fiddle for Hive.  It is pretty different from other databases.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one option that uses window functions: you can get the next WiFi session with a window min; the trick is to order the frame by descending `id`:

```
select id, next_wifi_id
from (
    select t.*,
        min(case when session_type = 'WiFi' then id end) over(order by id desc) next_wifi_id
    from mytable t
) t
where session_type = 'Cell'
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=f10f6f676cc4991f6f6778df365597e4)** - this is Postgres, but the behavior is the same in Hive.

```
id | next_wifi_id
-: | -----------:
 1 |            2
 3 |            5
 4 |            5
```

Comment: Thank you for the fiddle! It really help me break it apart, to understand the windowing.